# What are optimal VMware Processors settings if host Windows PC has an i7-10510U?

Tags: vmware-workstation

The host CPU has 4 cores, 8 threads according to [the Intel spec sheet](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196449/intel-core-i710510u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz.html).  It also has 32GB of RAM and an SSD.

Answer (score 1):

> What are optimal VMware Processors settings if host Windows PC has an
> i7-10510U?

A general rule of thumb is to not apply too much / too many CPU resources to a guest machine.

I have an i7 like this with VMware Pro V16 on a Windows 11 Pro host. I assign Windows 10, Kali and Ubuntu machines with 1 processor and 2 cores. Guest machines function fast and well.

That is normally enough resource for a guest.

If you have a guest with heavy CPU load you might experiment to 2 processors and 4 cores but that would normally be the limit.

There is a tendency (see it in SU) where people put too many resources to a guest machine and slow down the host which slows down everything.

For memory I use 3 GB per guest. My host (any 64-bit machine) uses 4 GB, so that is 12 - 13 GB total on a 16 GB machine.

My host and my guests are all very fast.

Comment: so the thing John is getting at, is that when vmware time-slices CPU usage across the guests and host workloads, it will only offer time to a guest thread if the system can provide a hardware core to each virtual core defined on that guest. if the host has work or other guests are using those cores, the hypervisor will pause execution of the guests threads until it can schedule time synchronously across the required number of physical cores. VMWare calls this delay "CPU Ready Time" https://www.vladan.fr/what-is-vmware-cpu-ready/ .